# IP address not being saved to database using MySQLi

Tags: php, mysqli, ip

I tried to create a script which will save all the IP address that came to my website (for adwords checking purposes). However when I try, the code doesnt save to database at all. Here is the code:

```
<?php
session_start();

// Create connection
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "hashmicr_admineq", "monkeycool100", "hashmicr_sessionchecker");

date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Singapore');

$date = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
$query = "INSERT INTO sessioncheck(ipaddress,date) VALUES (".$_SERVER['SERVER_ADDR'].", ".$date.")";
$mysqli->query($query);


/* close connection */
$mysqli->close();
?>
```

This is placed on the top of the PHP page.

Did I miss on any steps?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Need to add **single quotes** as both the field values contain `non-numeric (other than 0-9)` characters.

You can insert only numeric without single quotes.

Corrected SQL:

```
$query = "INSERT INTO sessioncheck(ipaddress,date)
VALUES ('".$_SERVER['SERVER_ADDR']."', '".$date."')";
```